# List of TSX stocks with their sector and industry

Tags: equities, data, market-data

Is there a website that offers free download or API where I can get an up-to-date list of all securities listed on the TSX along with their sector/industry? I could scrape individual screens for each stock on the web, but I'd like to find a single source of data for all stocks...Thanks!

Comment: Which sector/industry classification scheme are you interested in?  There are lots to choose from.... NAICS, GICS (S&P/MSCI), DJICS (Dow Jones), ICB (FTSE), TRBC (Thomson Reuters).

Comment: @NorgateData Any one I can get, really...GICS would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have been using [Yahoo-ticker-downloader.py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Yahoo-ticker-downloader/) to download tickers from Yahoo! It returns **MOST** tickers from international exchanges and returns Ticker, Company Name, Exchange, Sector, and Category Number. Here are 1,500+ tickers form the Toronto & TSX Venture Exchanges: [You're Welcome](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4DM1BWIv_-IaG9rMFBFdDdOTFE/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, this is pretty much the best I will get. One thing, the two last columns in the sample file you provided are "categoryName" and "categoryNr" so I believe there is only one level (probably industry thus the most precise...so the sector could be inferred from the category provided) and not two (sector + industry), do you agree?

Comment: They should be sorted to see, for example code 422 == Asset Management, but I think they are the same for all stocks.

Answer (score 3):

The Toronto Stock Exchange has an API that returns all of the listed tickers in JSON format.  Unfortunately it does not contain the industry/sector data.

[https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsx/^*](https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsx/%5E*)

The `^*` at the end is a regular expression.

Comment: Using `^` instead of `.*` seems to give more results.


Worth noting that https://api.tmxmoney.com/en/migreport/search seems to give more results than this endpoint does.


Also, there is a TSXV enpoint: https://www.tsx.com/json/company-directory/search/tsxv/^

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the stock screener](http://web.tmxmoney.com/screener.php?locale=EN) provided by the exchange. You can specify your criteria (Exchange = Toronto) and once you get the results, you can click on "Edit columns" and add the Sector.

The results are limited to 400 per run, but you can easily split your search into chunks by your choice of filter. For example you can filter by Market Cap 0-100M, then 100M-200M, and so on. Takes a few minutes but gets you the full list in the end.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and the information is there. Two problems though : I need my data in downloadable format (e.g. csv file or web API), and also the result is limited to 400 but I require the entire TSX stocks listing. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Wikipedia has a simple table. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S%26P/TSX_Composite_Index

Comment: The information is not up to date (as of December 18, 2015) and this is far from all the listed companies on the Toronto Stock Exchange (this is only the TSX Composite index constituents) :\ Thanks

Answer (score -2):

There is a database from Quandl that shows EOD prices for stocks traded in the TSX and if you go to the documentation part of the database here https://www.quandl.com/data/XTSE/documentation/documentation, you can click on the link where it says "A full list of all stocks in this database, along with their ticker symbols, can be downloaded here." This lets you ownload the list of over 4000 companies trading stocks in the TSX. I don't think it shows the sector or industry of each company though...

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for the sector and industries of these companies...

Comment: Hi, user37317, welcome to Quant.SE! I agree with @ibiza this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Hi @BobJansen, you're right. Sorry! I'll try to be more careful and helpful next time.